# I am a fresh graduate. How can I impress my prospective employers?

Tags: job-search, hiring-process, applications, new-hires

I am a fresh college graduate. I've been applying for jobs related to my degree. How can I "impress" my prospective employers knowing that I only have the knowledge and not the experience, yet.

Comment: When you say impress, do you mean the 'convince them I'm worth it' type or the 'leave them in awe' type of impress?

Comment: This is a self-defeating pursuit. Best thing to do is simply show you're open to learning whatever they need and doing whatever they need. After you've been working a few years, you realize that what you learned in school is hopelessly trivial.

Answer (score 7):

If your prospective employer is any good, they want to hire people who

1. are smart.
2. get things done.

I suggest you work out how to tell the story of your time in college to emphasize those two traits, especially the second one.

Did you have a job while in college?  If so, write on your resume "financed 65% of my college tuition with my summer job at Dewey, Cheatham, and Howe"  (or whatever is true).  This supports your "gets things done" claim admirably.

Did you do anything arguably creative while in college?  If so describe it. For example, "In my EE microelectronics course my lab partner and I designed a solar-power hearing aid, using an innovative way of powering the transducer" (or whatever is true). This supports both "smart" and "gets things done" very well indeed.

Did you publish anything? If so, mention it. "gets things done." Similarly if you worked as a teaching assistant or in some other academic role, describe it.  For example, "I was chosen as organic chemistry teaching assistant because Prof. van t'Hoff saw the quality of my laboratory work."  "smart."  "gets things done."

Here's the thing: It's unlikely you'll be able to claim stuff like "issued patent 7,987,654 for superconducting shielded power transmission cable" or anything so spectacular. But to get through college you must be smart, and you must know how to get things done, even if they're standard coursework. Convince your prospective employer you have gotten things done, and intend to keep getting things done.

Tell the truth. And tell your story.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you realise it or not, you have experience. Perhaps not commercial and professional experience but you will have life experiences that you can relate to professional experiences.

One way to show you are aware of what is required to work in a team environment (often something employers look for in graduates) is to apply real world experiences of where you worked in a team. Did you have a job before where you worked with others? Have you ever played a team sport in high school / university? Have you taken part in team building exercises, perhaps at summer camps? Relating any / all of these to working within a team in a professional environment will impress. An example of how to put this to a potential employer is:

> I understand that teamwork is an integral part of what you do here and I know my experience playing football will be valuable here. When I played football I had to communicate closely with my teammates to ensure each play ran smoothly. We worked hard to integrate well together and I believe the skills I learnt about teamwork whilst playing Football would serve me well integrating with the team here.

Look at what your the Job you are applying for requires and then try to apply the above technique to as many points as possible. Show them that whilst you lack professional experience, you have transferable skills. Everyone has transferable skills to some degree. It's recognising these and expounding your virtues to your future employer

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, don't try to "impress" - you are more likely to fall flat on your face than not because you don't know the company culture, the staff & management, the procedures and the rationale behind the procedures, the relationships the company has with its customers, vendors and service providers, etc. There are very few things that people like me dislike more than uninformed criticism from the new kid on the block. If your criticism is poorly founded, that could cost you your job prospects with your prospective employer.

The top impression you must give a company recruiter is that you are someone that the recruiter would love to work with as a colleague. Employers hire on potential, especially at this stage of your professional life when you just staring out and you are a (very) short track record. So show them you have potential - intelligence, a well written resume, the ability to listen, coolness under pressure, team spirit, etc.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.  The OP is applying for jobs, this answer is about being a new employee.

Comment: @jcm: you're right. I'll revise my post shortly. As in right now :)

Comment: I don't think this is the kind of impressing he had in mind. I'm thinking more towards CV-related stuff instead of performing a breakdance at your interview.